# Why doesn't str.replace replace ALL values in selected pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I'm working on a huge file that has names in columns that contain extraneous values (like the "|" key) that I want to remove, but for some reason my `str.replace` function only seems to apply to some rows in the column.

My column in the dataframe `summary` looks something like this:

```
Labels
test|test 1
test 2
test 3
test|test 4
test|test 5
test 6
```

As you can see, some columns are already how i want them to be, only containing the name "test #", but some have "test|" in front, which I want removed.

My function to remove them is like this:

```
correction = summary["Labels"].str.replace('test\|', '')
```

It seems to work for most of the values, but when I check for pipes ("|") in the dataframe (once i merged `correction` with `summary`), it says it finds 9330 of them:

```
found = summary[summary['Labels'].str.contains('|',regex=False)]
print(len(found))
print(found['Labels'].value_counts())

Results
9330
test|test-667     59
test|test-765     40
test|test-1810    39
test|test-685     36
test|test-1077    33
                  ..
```

Does anyone know why this is, and how i can fix it?

Comment: Any chance there could something like be `testtest||test-667`?

Comment: In the function you wrote, `correction` is a `series`. But when you are looking for errors, `correction` is a `dataframe`. So you are actually not showing us what you *really* did...

Comment: @Aryerez ah you're right sorry, forgot to add that i put ```correction``` into the ```summary``` dataframe after removing the unwanted values. i've corrected the code above to reflect that!

Comment: @Emily It is possible that your problem comes from combining `correction` and `summary` the wrong way, which we can't know since you are not showing us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track. Replace raw string as follows

```
summary['Labels'] = summary['Labels'].str.replace(r'test\|','', regex=True)



Labels
0  test 1
1  test 2
2  test 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `str.extract`:

```
df['Labels'] = df['Labels'].str.extract(r'\|(.*)', expand=False) \
                           .combine_first(df['Labels'])
print(df)

# Output
   Labels
0  test 1
1  test 2
2  test 3
3  test 4
4  test 5
5  test 6
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried this and it still doesn't seem to work, not sure why